# How do you unlock level caps of Palicos and Prowlers?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

My palico is stuck at level 20, and the level indicator is orange. How do I increase the level cap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first increase the level cap to **35** from 20 by either:

- Clear "The Grandmeowster's Trials" (Guild 4★, Prowler-only)
- Get to HR 6. (Clear your 5★ -> 6★ urgent)

You can then increase the level cap to **50** by either:

- Clear "Meownster Hunter" (Guild 7★, Prowler-only)

  - Clear "The Ball's in Your Court" (Guild 7★, Prowler-only) first to unlock this quest
- Get to HR 30.